# Spring integration- missing custom IBM MQ JMS headers

Tags: jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using IBM MQ clients(9.1.5.0) at sender side along with Spring integration at receiver side. I doubt this is not Spring's issue but no clue where my headers are getting trimmed off.
I am using below method to set a header property at producer side.

```java
message.setStringProperty("fileName", "someValue")
```

When I receive the message I see all custom headers I added are not there. Checked below method in debug mode at receiver side.

```
ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage
```

Any hint at what's going wrong here?
**Update:**
Had to set target client to 0(MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT) on sender side to preserve the headers.

Comment: If you perform a test and receive the message with your bare IBM MQ client (i.e. no Spring) are the custom properties there?

Comment: Does IBM MQ have any kind of admin tool where you can look at the message on the broker and confirm it has the custom properties?

Comment: I fear I cant see message from broker. Internally its calling WMQMessageProducer.sendInternal method at sender side and from there onward, I am loosing track of custom headers.

Comment: I'm not talking about using the debugger. I mean that you should send the message to the broker and *then* look at the message in the queue with some kind of IBM admin tool (assuming such a tool exists) to see if the properties are there. Of course, the consumer should be disabled for this test so that the message stays in the queue.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I will try to get message details from broker.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful admin tool could be [rfhutil](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil)